# Verifying Green`s theorem where boundaries are semicircle

Tags: integration

I have problem with verifying Green`s theorem for integral:
$$\int _C (x^2+y^2+\cos(x))dx+(x^2+y^2+\sin(y))dy$$
C is the boundary of the semicircle:
$$\{(x,y) \in R^2: x^2+y^2\leqslant4 \wedge x\geqslant0\}$$

Comment: proving or verifying ?

Comment: You`re right, verifying, sorry.

Comment: its okay :) so basically you need to show that the closed loop line integral equals the double integral of curl of given vector field

Comment: maybe start by parameterizing the path

Comment: Yes, I know that I should parametrize path, but after parametrizing curve I have in integral something like sin(2cos(x)).

Comment: Yeah I see that doesn't look pleasant to integrate >.<

Answer (score 0):

Parametrise the boundary by the line connecting (-2,0) and (2,0) (choose $x$ as parameter) (in that direction) and the circle by its angle $\theta$. The contourintegral then becomes the sum of the integrals over both the straight line and the circle. I assume the straight line does not pose any problems. The part of the circle becomes:
$$
2\int_0^\pi \left[ 4(\cos \theta - \sin \theta) -\sin(\theta)\cos(2\cos(\theta)) + \cos(\theta)\sin(2\sin(\theta)) \right]d\theta
$$
Now take a look at the derivative of $\cos(\sin(\theta))$:
$$
(\cos(\sin(\theta)))' = -\sin(\sin(\theta))\cos(\theta)
$$
Appart from a constant factor this is exactly what we're asked to integrate. Therefor the integral becomes:
$$
2\int_0^\pi \left[ 4(\cos \theta - \sin \theta) +\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\theta}\sin(2\cos(\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\theta}\cos(2\sin(\theta))  \right]d\theta
$$
For which you are now able to apply the first main theorem of calculus. (at least on the second part of the integral)